# Configuring Openfire server

Tags: openfire

While setting up the openfire server, I am facing issues in connecting to the database. Also the admin account is not getting created.
I followed the steps given here:
"https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/database.html"
Have tried almost everything. Please if someone could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the schema. Create a new schema and no tables in it.

Please make sure your server and database in same system. If your database is in different system please check whether remote access is enabled in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

First create an empty database with name `openFire` in database and then use

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://[SERVERNAME]/[DATABASE];appName=jive;instance=[NAMEDINSTAN EC]
```

in my case the string was

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://TelUpd01/openFire;appName=jive;instance=SQLEXPRESS
```

Use this configuration string while installation.